# Swap widgets in QGraphicsView fails

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to create a timeline widget.
I've a `Row` class that I insert in a `Timeline` widget, using `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView`.

If I insert three rows in order, I can show them in the widget.

Then I want to drag them in order to reorder rows. For example, if I have

```
+----------------------+
|  Row 1               |
+----------------------+
|  Row 2               |
+----------------------+
|  Row 3               |
+----------------------+
```

If I drag Row 1 between Row2 and Row3 I obtain

```
+----------------------+
|  Row 2               |
+----------------------+
|  Row 1               |
+----------------------+
|  Row 3               |
+----------------------+
```

And so on.

When I start dragging the reordering works, but after some dragging (I drag always the first row between the other two) drag stops. I can't drag anymore the first row. Then I start to drag another row and then it works again.

These are the classes that I've used (I can't use only hpp files because of moc files):

Row class:

```
#ifndef ROW_HPP_
#define ROW_HPP_

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QObject>

const qreal TopZValue{ std::numeric_limits<qreal>::max() };

class Row : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  Row();
  virtual ~Row() = default;
  void setBrush(const QBrush& b);
  void setOrigin(int x, int y);
  void setHeight(int height);
  int getHeight() const;
  const QPoint& getOrigin() const;

public:

  virtual QRectF boundingRect() const override;
  virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;

signals:

  void originUpdated(const QPoint& origin);

protected:

  virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
  virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
  virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;

private:

  void drawBackground(QPainter* painter);

private:

  QBrush m_background;
  int m_height = 0;
  int m_width = 0;
  QPoint m_origin;
  qreal m_zValueWhenDragged = 0.0;
};

#endif // !ROW_HPP_

// CPP file
#include "Row.hpp"

Row::Row() :
  QGraphicsItem(nullptr) {
  setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
  setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
  setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
}

void Row::setBrush(const QBrush& b) {
  m_background = b;
}

void Row::setOrigin(int x, int y) {
  m_origin.rx() = x;
  m_origin.ry() = y;
  setPos(0, 0);
}

void Row::setHeight(int height) {
  m_height = height;
}

int Row::getHeight() const {
  return m_height;
}

const QPoint& Row::getOrigin() const {
  return m_origin;
}

QRectF Row::boundingRect() const {
  return QRectF(m_origin.x(), m_origin.y(), m_width, m_height);
}

void Row::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) {
  Q_UNUSED(option)
  Q_UNUSED(widget)
  drawBackground(painter);
  QGraphicsView *view = scene()->views().first();
  m_width = view->width();
  painter->drawRect(m_origin.x(), m_origin.y(), m_width, m_height);
}

void Row::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
  m_zValueWhenDragged = zValue();
  QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void Row::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
  setZValue(TopZValue);
  QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void Row::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
  setZValue(m_zValueWhenDragged);
  QPoint newOrigin(0, m_origin.y() + scenePos().toPoint().y());
  m_origin = newOrigin;
  emit originUpdated(newOrigin);
  QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}

void Row::drawBackground(QPainter* painter) {
    auto brush = painter->brush();
    auto width = painter->viewport().width();
    painter->setBrush(m_background);
    painter->drawRect(m_origin.x(), m_origin.y(), width, m_height);
    painter->setBrush(brush);
}
```

Timeline class:

```
#ifndef TIMELINE_HPP_
#define TIMELINE_HPP_

#include "Row.hpp"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>

class Timeline : public QWidget {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  Timeline(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~Timeline() = default;
  size_t addRow(Row* row);
  size_t getNumberOfRows() const;

private slots:

  void setRowOrigin(const QPoint& origin);

private:

  void orderRowsOriginsByTheirPosition();

private:

  QGraphicsView* m_view;
  QGraphicsScene* m_scene;
  QHBoxLayout* m_layout;
  std::vector<Row*> m_rows;
};

#endif //!TIMELINE_HPP_

// CPP file
#include "Timeline.hpp"

Timeline::Timeline(QWidget* parent) :
  QWidget(parent) {
  m_view = new QGraphicsView(this);
  m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
  m_layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
  m_layout->addWidget(m_view);
  m_view->setScene(m_scene);
  m_view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
}

size_t Timeline::addRow(Row* row) {
  m_rows.push_back(row);
  m_scene->addItem(row);
  orderRowsOriginsByTheirPosition();
  connect(row, &Row::originUpdated, this, &Timeline::setRowOrigin);
  return getNumberOfRows();
}

size_t Timeline::getNumberOfRows() const {
  return m_rows.size();
}

void Timeline::setRowOrigin(const QPoint& origin) {
  Q_UNUSED(origin)
  orderRowsOriginsByTheirPosition();
}

void Timeline::orderRowsOriginsByTheirPosition() {
  int offsetY = 0;
  std::sort(m_rows.begin(), m_rows.end(), [] (Row* left, Row* right) { return left->getOrigin().y() < right->getOrigin().y();});
  for (auto& it : m_rows) {
    it->setOrigin(0, offsetY);
    offsetY += it->getHeight();
  }
  m_scene->update();
  m_view->update();
}
```

MainWindow class:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "Timeline.hpp"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow() = default;

private:

  Timeline* m_timeline;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

// CPP file
#include "MainWindow.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  m_timeline(new Timeline(this)) {
  setCentralWidget(m_timeline);
  setMinimumSize(300, 200);

  auto row1 = new Row();
  row1->setHeight(40);
  m_timeline->addRow(row1);
  row1->setBrush(Qt::red);
  auto row2 = new Row();
  row2->setHeight(30);
  m_timeline->addRow(row2);
  row2->setBrush(Qt::blue);
  auto row3 = new Row();
  row3->setHeight(50);
  m_timeline->addRow(row3);
  row3->setBrush(Qt::green);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Row.hpp"
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

When I start the program I obtain:

[image]

Then I drag the red row between the green and the blue:

[image]

Now I can't drag the green row, but if I drag another one in another position, I can drag the green one again.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change `Row::m_origin` you change the value returned by `Row::boundingRect()` without calling `QGraphicsItem::prepareGeometryChange()`.

But Qt documentation states:

> If you want to change the item's bounding rectangle, you must first
>   call prepareGeometryChange(). This notifies the scene of the imminent
>   change, so that it can update its item geometry index; otherwise, the
>   scene will be unaware of the item's new geometry, and the results are
>   undefined (typically, rendering artifacts are left within the view).

---

Also you could make it with a simpler code.

- Remove `m_origin` and use `QGraphicsItem::pos()` and `QGraphicsItem::setPos()`.
- `Row::boundingRect()` can now simply return `QRectF(0.0, 0.0, m_width, m_height)` and you call `QGraphicsItem::prepareGeometryChange()` only when changing `m_width` or `m_height`.
- Same goes for `Row::paint()`

This way you can leverage the QGraphicsScene positioning system, without having to handle changes in geometry.

---

On a side not instead of `class Row : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem` you could write `class Row : public QGraphicsObject`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't understand well the `prepareGeometryChange()` method. I'm new to this part of Qt... And also thanks for other precious suggestions.